# Wi-Fi Direct and Android Support

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I am wanting to use Wi-Fi Direct in a solution but am unsure which platforms will support it.

Is Wi-Fi Direct dependent on phone type or Android version?

I need to know if I can develop an App with Wi-Fi direct features on a Xiaomi running MIUI version of Android 4.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Android Developer site Wifi-Direct tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html)

Wifi Direct support was added in API level 14, i.e. ICS, so the phone you specify is likely supporting the feature.